# "harden ignorance in contempt" and "distinguish desert"

Tags: phrase-meaning, early-modern-english

In his Preface to the Dictionary, Samuel Johnson wrote the following. I'd like to know what "harden ignorance in contempt" and "distinguish desert" mean.

> ... a few wild blunders, and risible absurdities, from which no work of such multiplicity was ever free , may for a time furnish folly with laughter, and **harden ignorance in contempt**; but useful diligence will at last prevail and there can never be wanting some who **distinguish desert**; who will consider that no dictionary of a living tongue ever can be perfect, since, while it is hastening to publication, some words are budding, and some falling away.'

I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

That's an older meaning of **desert**; the phrase **who distinguish desert** means "who recognize merit".

The inevitable mistakes and shortcomings of a work of such scope and variety as the dictionary may cause folly (i.e. the foolish) to laugh and cause ignorance [i.e. the ignorance of the ignorant] to set or congeal into a (lasting) contempt [for the work].

Comment: There is irony in this topic, for those that can see it.

Comment: Any reference for the claim that "folly" means "foolish people"?

Comment: It's *personification* to say that folly can be furnished with laughter.

Comment: It's Johnson's way of saying "my blunders may give fools a chuckle".

Answer (score -2):

I wouldn't be bothered if you find this language hard to understand. The man was a snob. He deliberately wrote in obscure metaphors to show off.

"Harden ignorance in contempt" seems to be saying some had pointed out errors in previous versions of his dictionary and used that to dismiss the value of the project. He suggests the consequence of their contempt is to make their ignorance worse.

And "distinguish desert"? Note, he used 'desert' = sand, not 'dessert' = ice cream. I think that is just saying some people always see the worst in everything.

Comment: I don't give a damn about down votes, but doing so without a comment as to why does not help the questioner, and it does not help me get it right next time if I have made some sort of error.

Comment: There is no way to tell who cast up- or down-votes, but, for what it's worth, it seems to me personally that your answer seems heavily loaded with your own opinion about Doctor Johnson - "he was a snob"; and also a rather weak stab at guessing what "distinguish desert" might mean. These features (particularly the first) tend to get an answer considered "low quality". A high quality answer confines itself to facts, not opinions, backed up by references

Comment: Thank you, @Michael Harvey, for those comments. If whoever cast the down vote had added a comment along those lines I would probably have agreed a down vote was justified.